# Another way to display questions

Tags: feature-request

I've noticed that sometimes, with so many question/min a question can be left un-answered with very few people viewing it.

and out of those 3-4 people who view it, what is the chance that one of them is an expert / been in a similar situation.

So I think there should be a smarter way to display questions.
I haven't figured  out this idea until the last bit , 
but I think, that based on my preference, my questions asked, and the answers I've given the system can have a general idea what are my fields of expertise.

So - I think that the first ten questions displayed in my 50 Q page - should be question with one of those tags (that the system know I use a lot) and below them, any other new  questions will be inserted.

so- questions that I have a better chanse for knowing the answer will be stay "longer" under my radar, and the rest - will start from the middle of the page.

This system is adjustable (if I answer a question from "below" in a new topic - it will be added to my expertise) and I think in result will get more questions reach their right destination.

Just an Idea.

Dani

Comment: Hm... much of this was done as part of [the effort to redesign the Stack Overflow homepage](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/). The end result is that the front page now places bias on your favorite tags, the tags you perform well in, as well as those with fewer answers. Have you tried out the front page yet?

Comment: perhaps a 'Cold' tab, which would display questions more than X hours old with low views.